# Laravel Public url for storage files

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-5.4, php-7

I want to retrieve public url for all the files stored using

> storage::putFile('public/spares');

So, this is the issue I'm using

> storage::files('public/spares');

but it provides this output from laravel storage directory

```
public/spares/image1.jpg
public/spares/image2.jpg
public/spares/image3.jpg
```

how can I get the public link for the above

```
http://localhost/laravel/public/storage/spares/image1.jpg
http://localhost/laravel/public/storage/spares/image2.jpg
http://localhost/laravel/public/storage/spares/image3.jpg
```

**Edit **

Sending last modified data of files to view

```
$docs = File::files('storage/document');
$lastmodified = [];
foreach ($docs as $key => $value) {
   $docs[$key] = asset($value);
   $lastmodified[$key] = File::lastmodified($value);
}
return view('stock.document',compact('docs','lastmodified'));
```

Is this correct

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I'm using laravel 5.4

Answer (score 26, accepted):

What about `Storage::url`? It works even for local storage.

You can find more here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#file-urls

If you want to return all files' urls from the directory, you can do something like this:

```
return collect(Storage::files($directory))->map(function($file) {
    return Storage::url($file);
})
```

Don't forget to inject the `\Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemManager` instead of the `Storage` facade if you are looking for a not-facade way.

Edit:

There are 2 (or more) ways how you can deal with modified date:

**Pass files to the view.**

|ou can pass your `Storage::files($directory)` directly to the view and then in your template use following:

```
// controller:

return view('view', ['files' => Storage::files($directory)]);

// template:

@foreach($files as $file)
   {{ Storage::url($file) }} - {{ $file->lastModified }} // I'm not sure about lastModified property, but you get the point
@endforeach
```

**Return an array:**

```
return collect(Storage::files($directory))->map(function($file) {
     return [
         'file' => Storage::url($file),
         'modified' => $file->lastModified // or something like this
     ]
})->toArray()
```

Comment: it works for one file not getting array of files in the folder.

Comment: @DanielEuchar so why not to iterate through the folder ( `Storage::files($directory)` -
 https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#directories) and then use `Storage::url` for each file and return as a collection? I updated my answer.

Comment: never knew that will give it a go and update. thanks

Comment: Sure, we will figure it out! :) Let me know if it works

Comment: awesome it works, as well now to also attach last modified along with this data do i create a separate variable or is there a possibility to use collections ?

Comment: Great! Show me your code, I'm not sure what you want to achieve. Do you want to pass this collection and last modified information to the view?

Comment: sorry for the delayed response,  exactly what you just said, i have added the code in my question

Comment: Understand. I have updated my answer to show you an example.

Answer (score 32):

First you have to create the symbolic link from your `public/storage` directory to your `storage/app/public` directory so you can access the files.  You can do that with:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

So then you can store your documents with:

```
Storage::putFile('spares', $file);
```

And access them as an asset with:

```
asset('storage/spares/filename.ext');
```

Check out the [documentation on the public disk](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#the-public-disk)

Comment: what i wanted to achieve was get the list of files in the directory and display it in my view. The solution you have given works for single asset not for getting the full list.

Answer (score 5):

I know this question is quite old, but i am putting this answer for anyone still having this issue from laravel 5.5+

To solve the issue update your filesystem's configuration by adding the 'url' key like below:

```
'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$file = Storage::disk('public')->put($folder, request()->file($key), 'public');
$file = Storage::url($file);
```

Comment: Always give explanation to your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Well I figured out the solution, instead of searching the storage

```
$docs = Storage:files('public/spares');
```

we can search the symbolic link

```
$docs = File:files('storage/spares');
```

then run it through the `asset()` function to get the public URL. Is there a better solution?